# Static Java

Tags: java

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста. Есть код :

```
public class A {
    public static int a = 0;
    public int b = 0;

    public A() {
        this.b = a++;
    }
    public static int get() {
        return new A().b + a;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(get());
        System.out.println(get());
        System.out.println(get());
    }
}
```

Скажите пожалуйста, как почему компилируется эта строка :

```
return new A().b + a;
```

Ведь метод get() объявлен как static, а это значит, что он может работать только со статическими полями? Объясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3):

А почему ему не работать. С `a` проблем нет - это поле статическое.

А вот обращение к полю `b` на первый взгляд выглядит странно.  Но дело в том, что к этому полю не обращаются напрямую - а через создание нового объекта. А запрета на вызов конструктора с статического метода нет.

Comment: Скажите, а где найти правила, для static методов. смотрел тут  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.2, но ничего толкового не нашел ?

Comment: а какие правила хотите увидеть? мол "вызывать конструктор можно"? Но я думал, что это и так понятно, иначе ни одна программа бы не работала. Ведь главный метод, который запускает все - main - статический.

Документация - это конечно хорошо. Но думаю, что лучше почитать хорошую книжку.

Comment: Я имею в виду, что A().b - это способ обращения к полю b. Но ведь поле само поле b не статическое. И как проходит это вызов мне не понятно.

Comment: Создается экземпляр класса `A` (`new A()`) и происходит обращение к полю `b` этого экземпляра.

Answer (score 0):

в статическом методе get() вы создаете новый объект класса А, после чего возможно обращение к нестатическим членам класса А через вновь созданный объект. Тоесть вы в методе get создаете как-бы временный объект, который уничтожается сразу после выполнения возложенной на него обязанности изменить переменную а.

Тоесть у вас класс:

```
public class SomeClass {
    static Class nameclass = new Class(); // Статический - значит общий объект для всех экземпляров SomeClass будь их хоть тысяча, все равно оги будут иметь общее поле nameclass, да и при отсутствии объектов SomeClass nameclass все равно существует
    ... // другие методы и поля
}
/*где-то внутри другого класа вы можете обратиться к nameclass без   создания объекта SomeClass(одно из применений static)*/

SomeClass.nameclass.someMethodOfClass();
// Создаем 2 объекта класса SomeClass
ob1 = new SomeClass();
ob2 = new SomeClass();
// Предположим у класса Class есть поле someValue равное 0 на данный момент
ob1.nameclass.someValue = 100500;
System.out.println(ob2.nameclass.someValue); // выведет 100500, а если бы nameclass был не статический, мы получили бы 0
```

Это второе применение static: для ob1 и ob2 nameclass общая переменная, изменения в которой из одного объекта сразу же видны из другого.

Comment: этот static вообще понять не могу. а что тогда это такое static Class nameclass = new Class() ? Как экземпляр класса может быть static ? И самое главное зачем ? Пример взял из Философии Java

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснение. Даже в спецификации не мог такого найти. Эта Философия для меня сложна (плюс еще пытаюсь и в оригинале читать). Скажите, а зачем это вообще нужно ? Этот способ создать экземпляр класса где то применяется ?

Comment: да, подобный способ применяется для создания синглтонов - объектов, которые должны существовать в единственном экземпляре. Но обычно static классы являются причиной утечек (как минимум в андроиде).

Comment: Основное применение static в Java - это использование статических методов в различных библиотеках, например, в стандартной Math используются только статические методы:

    class Math {
        public static long round(double a);
        public static int abs(int a);
    ...
    }
    // В программе мы вызываем эти методы напрямую, без предварительного создания экземпляра Math, который и не нужен вообще
    double val1 = Math.round(Math.abs(val2));